# Git clone/pull from windows to raspberry pi in local network

Tags: linux, windows, git, raspberry-pi

I have bare repo on my windows machine `C:/Users/Public/Git_Server/test-repo.git`

I can git clone in to my working dir on my windows machine using `git clone C:/Users/Public/Git_Server/test-repo.git` but I also want to be able to clone it to raspberry pi which is on my local network.

I can ssh to my rpi and try `git clone //PCNAME/Git_Server/test-repo.git` (`\\PCNAME\Git_Server` is a shared network path) but it's gives me an error:

```
fatal: repository '//PCNAME/Git_Server/test-repo.git' does not exist
```

I browsed all stackoverflow but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: You local PC isn't a git server. Why not just `ssh` into the Pi and clone from the original source repository? Otherwise you will need software running on your windows PC that is a server hosting the repository for cloning, etc... That's relatively easy with a Linux box running a web-server like `apache` or `nginx`, but I'm not familiar with the same for Windows.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't want to expose this repo to internet, I would use github or gitlab otherwise. I want to keep it in my local network

Comment: I got you, but I presume both your PC and Pi are on your local network behind some type of router or firewall -- right? So unless you have opened external ports 80 and 443 and pointed them to your PC's IP, you wont have any incoming traffic from the internet. You can run a server on your local network without exposing it to the internet. My point being, that without some server software running, you are not making your repo hosted on your PC available for cloning by anything. A cloned repository is just that, it isn't automatically made available for cloning itself.

Comment: It would much easier if you put the bare repo on raspberry pi, so you can `git clone` from Windows using ssh.